# Synchronous HTTP requests in Node.js

Tags: node.js, web-services, http, asynchronous, requestify

I've got three components `A`, `B` and `C`.
When `A` sends an HTTP request to `B`, `B` sends another HTTP request to `C`, retrieves the relative content and sends it back to `A`, as an HTTP response.

The `B` component is represented by the following Node.js snippet.

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

// sends an HTTP request to C and retrieves the response content
function remoterequest(url, data) {
  var returnedvalue;
  requestify.post(url, data).then(function(response) {
    var body = response.getBody();
    // TODO use body to send back to the client the number of expected outputs, by setting the returnedvalue variable
  });
  return returnedvalue;
}

// manages A's request
function manageanotherhttprequest() {
  // [...]
  var res = remoterequest(url, data);
  // possible elaboration of res
  return res;
}
```

I need to return `body` content as a result of the `remoterequest` function.
I notices that, currently, the POST request is asynchronous. Hence, the `returnedvalue` variable is never assigned before returning it to the calling method.

How can I execute synchronous HTTP requests?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `restify` which will return `promise` once its called for its methods(`post`, `get`..etc ). But the method you created `remoterequest` is not returning `promise` for you to wait using `.then`. You can make it to return `promise` using `async-await` or built-in `promise` as below:

- using promise:

  ```
  var requestify = require('requestify');

  // sends an HTTP request to C and retrieves the response content
  function remoterequest(url, data) {
    var returnedvalue;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      requestify.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
        var body = response.getBody();
        // TODO use body to send back to the client the number of expected outputs, by setting the returnedvalue variable
      });
      // return at the end of processing
      resolve(returnedvalue);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  // manages A's request
  function manageanotherhttprequest() {
    remoterequest(url, data).then(res => {
      return res;
    });
  }
  ```
- using async-await

  ```
  var requestify = require('requestify');

  // sends an HTTP request to C and retrieves the response content
  async function remoterequest(url, data) {

    try {
      var returnedvalue;
      var response = await requestify.post(url, data);
      var body = response.getBody();
      // TODO use body to send back to the client the number of expected outputs, by setting the returnedvalue variable
      // return at the end of processing
      return returnedvalue;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    };
  }

  // manages A's request
  async function manageanotherhttprequest() {
      var res = await remoterequest(url, data);
      return res;
  }
  ```

Comment: I don't understand why it should work. Being an asynchronous request, everything inside of the function is in practice executed after the calling method has returned.

Comment: @auino, see i updated answer, please revert back if you have any question.